# Will electoral college benefit smaller states or bigger states?

Tags: united-states

I've heard about the following mathematical analysis

Mathematically speaking the effect of your vote is inversely proportional to the standard deviation of the votes in your state but proportional to the number of voters (or population) in your state. So voters in bigger state have an edge proportional to the square root of number.

Assume everyone votes by flipping coins and you want to compute the probability that the president change because of your coin flip. That's how powerful your vote is.

That's proportional to the square root of the number of "people" in your state.

So yea, bigger states have an edge.

Wait a minute. That means popular votes benefit smaller states, not bigger states. I guess some assumption may be wrong.

Imagine a federal president campaigning to take money from Nevada and giving it to Texas.

Say, hypothetically, of course, Bob run as a president by proposing taxing states that start with letter N and give money to state with letter T. Obviously more in Texas would like it and people in Nevada would oppose it.

Will it work better under popular votes or electoral colleges?

How would his campaign work under popular votes vs electoral colleges?

https://www.dailysignal.com/2019/07/19/maine-and-nevada-show-why-the-electoral-college-helps-small-states-not-red-states

Anyone with good math model?

I am very confused.

**Note:**

I am aware that people don't vote by flipping coins. That's an approximation.

Some would say that people don't flip coins when voting. Median vote theorem will ensure that the twin candidate that shows up in election are moderate that most voters should be indifferent which one is better if not for artificial made up nonsense like pro life vs pro choices.

When voters are indifferent, they flip coins. That's from game theory analysis.

For example, the amount of tax rate a democracy will have is something that's about right to win the votes from median voters.

As for taking money from Nevada and giving it to Texas. The idea is that a presidential candidate would propose things that benefit some voters and hurt other voters. He'll do it in ways that maximize his chance of winning.

I wonder if the 2 system will make the presidential candidate to favor bigger state or smaller states to get the median votes.

In Indonesia, we have popular votes and Jokowi build lots of road in non Java sparsely populated provinces.

Comment: How your question is written it is very confusing. Could you please [edit](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/43300/edit) it to clarify?

Comment: It took some math to understand. Basically, I want to know how different system affect benefits for a typical citizen.

Answer (score 3):

The Electoral College doesn't just group state votes (and in fact, it doesn't necessarily group state votes; Maine and Nebraska vote by Congressional district).  Another thing that it does is apportion votes by Congressional representation.  That apportionment increases the influence of small states relative to big states.

For example, California has a population of almost 40 million and Wyoming's population is under 600 thousand (2018 census estimate).  That gives California a little more than 68 times as many people as Wyoming.  But Wyoming gets 3 Electoral College votes and California gets 55.  That's little more than 18.3 times as many Electoral College votes.

A third thing that the Electoral College does is that it makes states with a strong partisan lean less important.  In California, the result isn't in doubt.  A Democrat will win all of the states Electoral College votes.  So there's no reason to campaign in California nor to offer it goodies for its vote.  The same thing's true of Wyoming but in reverse.  It's a guaranteed win for the Republican.

The states that matter are those that might vote either way.  North Carolina, Florida, Pennsylvania, Michigan, and Wisconsin are all states that voted for Donald Trump in 2016 but Barack Obama in 2008.

With the popular vote, votes in both California and Wyoming would matter again.  Because it wouldn't just be who got more votes but how many more votes.  So for the many states that aren't currently competitive (which is most states), a popular vote is better for creating influence for that state.

I get where you're coming from with your probabilistic model.  But these other effects of the Electoral College have a larger impact.  California would be much better off with a popular vote, both because it would be more likely to get its favored candidate and because it would be more influential.  Campaigns would have more reason to court it because it would have more power to affect the final result.  Gaining an extra million votes in California would be useful again, where now it isn't.  Also, its contribution to the vote would increase from about a tenth of the Electoral College to an eighth of the popular vote.